# How to set APNS Auth path on Heroku vapor app

Tags: swift, heroku, vapor

[image][image][image]How do you reference a file path when a vapor swift application is deployed on Heroku? This works on my local, but not when I deploy to Heroku. the local machine I added file path in environment variable like this APNS_AUTH_KEY_PATH: $(SRCROOT)/apikeys/AuthKey_Y8HP6L5K6P.p8 and it's working fine on the local machine. Added the same key path on the Heroku application config variable. But its saying, not able find file and application crashed on Heroku

Comment: Fatal error: FCM serviceAccount file doesn't exists at path: $(SRCROOT)/apikeys/serviceAccountKey.json

Comment: `$(SRCROOT)` shouldn't work, use absolute paths instead for both FCM and APNS libs

Comment: Absolute path means like this.  /apikeys/serviceAccountKey.json I used to like this but no success.

Comment: I added this path to the Heroku Config variable.  apikeys/serviceAccountKey.json. Still, I am getting same error. Fatal error: FCM service account file doesn't exist at path: /apikeys/serviceAccountKey.json

Comment: and my local directory path is: "/Users/chandrakant/Documents/VaporRandD/ashi-apns/apikeys/serviceAccountKey.json" It working on the local machine

Comment: absolute path means absolute path from the root `/`, it should work all the time. connect to heroku via ssh and try to access file at path `/apikeys/serviceAccountKey.json` to make sure that it is exists.

Comment: Yes, the file exists there. That why it's working in a local machine. Attached image for changed. Please see and let me know its correct.

Comment: I changed the config variable path and run the Heroku app again. still failing. 2020-06-21T07:13:29.227835+00:00 app[web.1]: Fatal error: FCM serviceAccount file doesn't exists at path: /apikeys/serviceAccountKey.json

Comment: Let me test it by myself on heroku. Btw let's switch out conversation to Discord, find me there as iMike#3049

Comment: I can't find a way to store config files on heroku safely like on classic linux machine.Do not put config file into git repository cause it is not safe.

Comment: With FCM library you can use `.envServiceAccountKeyFields` and with it you should pass `FCM_EMAIL`, `FCM_PROJECT_ID`, and `FCM_PRIVATE_KEY` in config vars and it will work on heroku without any configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{SRCROOT}` is an Xcode concept that doesn't translate to Linux. So you either have to copy the key over into Heroku and reference the fully qualified path or just inject the contents of the key as the environment variables itself. The second option is far better as you're not committing the key into source control